# Multiple instances of VUEjs in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Good morning! How can I work with multiple instances of VUEjs in Laravel?

I want to work with the components in some parts of the project and in other occasions I want to instantiate VUE directly in the view and do the logic there but I have the problem that I can't work with both at the same time.

If I want to work with the components I must leave the **"const app new Vue"** of the app.js file. But if I leave this file like this it won't work in the views.
how can i do it? Thank you!

app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';


require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('eliminar-registro', require('./components/EliminarRegistro.vue').default);
Vue.component('modal-encuestas', require('./components/ModalEncuestas.vue').default);
Vue.component('abrir-modal', require('./components/AbrirModal.vue').default);
Vue.component('ejemplo-prueba', require('./components/EjemploPrueba.vue').default);


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice how your vue instance mounts to an element

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

This can be found in your `app.blade.php` or whatever layout you use

there will be a `<div id="app"></div>`

This is how you mount instances.

So now If you want a second instance

You can mount a second one to another div as long as the two divs are seperate

in app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#second-app',
});
```

Then in your `app.blade.php`

```
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="second-app"></div>
```

This will give you two seperate vue instances on the same page.